# How to join two floating 2x6 beams at a 90 degree angle

Tags: wood, woodworking

The beams are both 2x6", vertical and are meeting at 90 degrees, one beam is well supported from a foot or two back and the other is hanging.

Something like this:

[image]

My first thoughts were miter them together and throw a bed bolt going through each direction. Another idea was to do a vertical lap-type joint where I leave the bottom half of the supporting beam and rest the top half lap of the hanging beam on top of that, and then a strong-tie to hold it together.

It needs to be a decently strong connection, and I'm leaning more towards a deconstructible bolt system rather than nails/screws. Thoughts?

---

Comment: Full-on steel bracket. Skip the mitre joint.

Comment: Maybe this nail bed works, maybe you need a hanger. What is this for, what kind of load? Please provide a sketch showing all dimensions (lengths, cantilever), types of existing support, and detail the load/purpose. Welcome to DIY, and please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: A _lot_ more detail is needed, but at a minimum, skip the miter joint. Much harder than necessary to get it to look nice.